# How to make Curl and PHP available when installed from Xampp

Tags: 14.04, php, xampp, curl

I have installed a recent copy of XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I issue this command:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

I get the following error messages:

1. The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:

   > sudo apt-get install curl
2. The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:

   > sudo apt-get install php5-cli

So what gives, how do I make my implimentation of curl and PHP "visible".

Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What it means is that you don't have curl installed and you need to install curl to use it. This can be done by going to a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> then entering `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl`. This will install curl, php and the necessary libraries to provide you with the functionality that you need.

After the installation has completed, restart the server with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks for that. However, if I go do localhost I can see in phpinfo that curl *is enabled* as too obviously PHP. So I do not understand why ubuntu does not see it. Xampp is installed in /opt if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try the [solution outlined here](http://www.walkswithme.net/enable-curl-library-in-xampp-localhost). It is for windows, however the folder paths can be altered to suite that of ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds promising - but what about PHP not being seen either ? 

thanks !

Comment: Check my answer for an edit. You may already have some of the packages, however, if will just skip them.

Comment: @Vince libcurl and curl are different but related things. That the library is available/enabled in PHP does not mean that the program installed. Install the program as instructed if you want to use it. Programs installed locally (not via the package manager) need more configuration before they are seen elsewhere. That's why `php` from Xampp isn't visible.

Comment: I still can't qite get my head around this. The error message says that PHP is not installed, yet, the fact that I can do a "LocalHost" and a "phpinfo" clearly demonstrates that PHP is installed. 

I am concerned that if I install it again, then the php.ini file available through xampp will not be the active one, but rather some other one buried deep inside Ubuntu.

Comment: The error message. Can you you give the verbatim? i.e a screenshot would be best. Also try `apt-cache policy php5` this will show you weather of not php5 is installed, also post this screenshot in the edit of your question.

Comment: the edit command above in the answer worked great for me for a fresh wordpress install and a plugin that needed curl. Thanks!